# Play downloaded video MPMovieController

Tags: ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, asihttprequest

So I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to download a video file from my FTP. It downloads and I get this as the directory path to the file:

```
/Users/Matt_Sich/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/B7366FF2-7592-4ED0-ABC2-46BA111D0FF4/Documents/INWD.mp4
```

Ok now I want to play that video.... I would image that doing this would be easy but for some reason I can't manage to get it to work. All I get is a black view and that's it.

```
//NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Park_iPod" ofType:@"mp4"]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.PathString];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

(NOTE: self.PathString is the path to the downloaded file that I mentioned above)
It plays the video from the main bundle just fine so I'm sure that there's something wrong with the file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've downloaded your file you need to use `fileURLWithPath` to access the file, not `URLWithString`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath.PathString];
```

Answer (score 1):

This would get you the documents directory...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:([NSURL fileURLWithPath : self.PathString])];

    [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

    // Register for the playback finished notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        addObserver: self
        selector: @selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
        name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
        object: moviePlayer];

    // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
        name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
        object: moviePlayer];

    [self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```